# Algorithm_BIG_O

Tags: algorithm

I need help understanding/doing Big O Notation. I understand the purpose of it, I don't know how to determine the complexity.Below are the few examples which i currently retrieved from pass year paper for doing revision before exam! And i had provide my answer for some of the question, please do help me check whether if it correct or not, tq!   ##

1. Example 1:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; sqrt(i) < n; i++) 
       cout << i << endl;
   ```

Comment: You're question would be more well received if you explained how you came to the answers you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**first part :**

```
for (int i = 0; sqrt(i) < n; i++) 
     cout << i << endl;
```

`sqrt(i) < n` => `i < n^2` so this loop takes `O(n^2)`

**second part :**

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
```

outer loop run in `O(n) [ increments by constant ]`

```
while (k > 0){ // k >= 1
    k /= 2;
```

`k = n, n/2 , n/4 , ..... n/2^i`

inner loop will stop when k == 1,

`n/2^i = 1` => `2^i = n` => `i = log(n)`

so total = `O(n * log(n))`

**last part :**

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
k = k * 2;
```

takes `O(n)` because it increments by constant.

second loop :
    what is k value ?

```
k = 1 , i = 0
k = 2 , i = 1
k = 4 , i = 2
k = 8 , i = 3
k = 2^i 
when i == n loop stops
value of k = 2^n
```

so total order = `O(n + 2^n) = O(2^n)`

Answer (score 5):

1. The code will run until sqrt(i) >= n which means that i >= n^2 so it's `O(n^2)`
2. The outer loops runs n times, the inner loop runs log(n) so that's `O(n*log(n))`
3. the first loop is O(n), after that the value of k is 2^n so the second loop is O(2^n) so in total it's `O(n) + O(2^n) = O(2^n)`

Comment: You possibly mean `O(n) + O(2^n) = O(2^n)` for number three.

Answer (score -2):

```
O^1 = sequences of statements and conditions
O^n = loops
O^n*m = loops inside loops
```

Hope that helps.